# font size depending image size

Tags: php, image, imagick

I'm sorry for my English! 
I've this problem with imagick php and overlay text on an image.
Size of font is small when resize the width of image.
This is an example for two image width, first is 350px and second is 1728px:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kRo0.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TedDO.jpg

**$f->userFontSize** is the size of font that logged user choose to show on his image.

```
if(trim($_GET['full']) != 'si'){
$width = 350;
$height = 350;
} else {
$width =    getWidth($root . $f->imagePathFull);
$height =     getHeight($root . $f->imagePathFull);
}
$image = new imagick();
$draw = new imagickDraw();
$pixel = new imagickPixel('white');
$image->newImage($width, $height, $pixel);
$image->readImage($root . $f->imagePathNormal); 
$image->resizeImage ( $width, $height,  imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, TRUE);
$fontPath = $root . '/assets/fonts/Mermaid.ttf';
$draw->setFillColor('black');
$draw->setFont($fontPath);
$draw->setFontSize(12 + $f->userFontSize);
$draw->setGravity(1);
$draw->setTextAntialias(true);
$draw->setFillOpacity(".55");
$image->annotateImage($draw, 5,0, 0, "text text text");
$image->setImageFormat("jpg");

header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" );
echo $image->getImageBlob();
$image->clear();
```

When I print the image with resolution as 1728px the text is very small. How I do to do to increase font size depending image size?
Thank you! :)

Comment: If you know font size 12 is correct for your width of 350px then maybe do a little trial and error, for this example lets say font size 20 is suitable for your width of 1728px. We have possible font sizes of 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 and 20. The difference between your max width and min width in this scenario is 1378px, lets divide that by the possible font sizes (which is 9), so for every step of 153px roughly you want to increase the font size by one. The logic should stand but please adjust the exact variables to suit your project. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with this way, I calculated the percentage of width that text occupy on image at 350px and according to this I calculated the percentage at 1728px(or another width). I do cicle a some font size until when I find a size that is egual at percentage. The final result of my solution is non perfect but acceptable. This is the code:

```
$myCP = '40'; // increase o decrease font size.
for($i = 1; $i <= 500;$i++){
    $box = imagettfbbox($i, 0, $fontPath, "lorem ipsum");
    $lT = $box[2] - $box[0];
    $cP = round(($lT / $width) * 100,1);
    // $cP percentage of font width
    if($cP >= $myCP) { $newFontSize = $i; break; } else { continue; }
}
```